# When using apoc.load.html, Is it possible to return the full HTML rather than only text?

Tags: css, neo4j, css-selectors, jsoup, neo4j-apoc

Lets say I want to scrape the Neo4j RefCard found at: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/

And I would like to fetch a 'code' example along with its styling.  Here's my target. Notice that it has CSS treatment (font, color...):

[image: code with formatted font style]

...so in Neo4j I call the `apoc.load.html` procedure as shown here, and you can see it's no problem finding the content:

[image: code with highlighted options of tagName, attributes, and text]

It returns a map with three keys: `tagName`, `attributes`, and `text`.

[image: Options shown of tagName, attributes, and text. The text option is highlighted]

The text is the issue for me.  It's stripped of all styling. I would like for it to let me know more about the styling of the different parts of this text.

The actual HTML in the webpage looks like following image with all of these span class tags: `cm-string`, `cm-node`, `cm-atom`, etc.  Note that this was not generated by Neo4j's `apoc.load.html` procedure.  It came straight from my Chrome browser's inspect console.

[image: div tag element with class of listingblock with a direct pre tag filled with many span tags]

I don't need the actual fonts and colors, just the tag names.

I can seen in the [documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_html_page) that there is an optional `config` map you can supply, but there's no explanation for what can be configured there.  It would be lovely if I could configure it to return, say, HTML rather than text.

[image: Loaded data from HTML page in plain text without any styling]

The library that Neo4j uses for CSS selection here is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

So I am hoping to not strip the `<span>` tags, or otherwise, extract their class names for each segment of text.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not generate the HTML yourself from the properties in your object? It looks they are all span tags with 3 different classes depending on whether your using the property name, property value, or property delimiter?

That is probably how they are generating the HTML themselves.

Comment: I would happily generate the HTML myself if I could get the span class names returned to me.  The image I show above that reveals those span tags: cm-node, cm-atom... is not a result of the procedure call.  I had to inspect the webpage directly from a web browser to see that.

Comment: and can't you use that to generate your HTML? unless the span classes change? I might be a bit confused here, so apologies

Comment: No, it seems I cannot.  It's as if the apoc.load.html procedure does not 'see' the span tags. For example if instead of using the selector I used, if I just add span to that, like this:
**bold**
`listingblock pre:contains(age: 38) span`
I can find it in the page using the browser's own selector, but this apoc.load.html procedure returns nothing.

Comment: Ignore the **bold** above.

Comment: The procedure returns an object containing the properties shown in your 3rd picture. Knowing that you won't get the HTML returned from the function. Could you not generate the HTML after the object has been returned to you. You can then display the data in the object in whatever html that you want? 

If this is not what you were after then I am sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: Right, The third picture is the one with the yellow highlighted rectangle.  There’s no span information in there.  (The next picture, the 4th one with all the span tags intact was not generated by the procedural.)  Without thos span tags I would have to intelligently parse the ‘text’ and decide how to style it. Nope, don’t really want to go through that. :)

Comment: I know. You want an object to be returned that includes the HTML to display in the browser. What is stopping you from converting the object you are given, to the object that includes the HTML to display in the browser? Add the HTML to the object yourself?

Comment: I’m hoping for a less labor intensive solutio.

Comment: I understand. Let's hope someone else has one. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, two years later I revisited this question I posted, and did find a solution.  I'll keep it short.

The APOC procedure CALL apoc.load.html is using the scraping library Jsoup, which is not a full-fledged browser.  When it visits a page it reads the html sent by the server but ignores any javascript.  As a result, if a page uses javascript for inserting content or even just formatting the content, then Jsoup will miss the html that the javascript would have generated had it run.

So I have just tried out the service at **prerender.com**.  It's simple to use.  You send it a URL, it takes your url as an argument and fetches that page itself and executes the page's javascript as it does.  It returns the final result as static HTML.

So if I just call prerender.com with apoc.load.html then the Jsoup library will simply ask for the html and this time it will get the fully rendered html.  :)

You can try the following two queries and see the difference pre-rendering makes.  The span tags in this page are rendered only by javascript.  So if we call it asking for its span tags without pre-rendering we get nothing returned.

```
CALL apoc.load.html("https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/", {target:".listingblock pre:contains(age: 38) span"}) YIELD value
UNWIND value.target AS spantags
RETURN spantags
```

...but if we call it via the prender.com website, you will get a bunch of span tags and their content.

```
CALL apoc.load.html("https://service.prerender.cloud/https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/", {target:".listingblock pre:contains(age: 38) span"}) YIELD value
UNWIND value.target AS spantags
RETURN spantags
```